# Xamarin C#: center AXML elements vertically inside horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: c#, android, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog, timepicker

I have an `AlertDialog` created with `DialogBuilder` and I inflate the contents of an axml file as its view. I have a two level system of nested `LinearLayouts` with the outer vertically positioning two other ones with contents. One of these contents contains a `TextView` and a somewhat shrunk `TimePicker`. Here is the relevant part of the corresponding axml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:text="Start"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="0.80"
            android:scaleY="0.80"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:id="@+id/endPicker" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is how it looks like on my smartphone (AM/PM is in my mothertongue):

[image]

The text START refers to the start of a period of time and I want to align it  vertically to the center of the time picker something like this (which is oc a manually modified pic):

[image]

For some reason, however, I cannot do that, no matter, how I align my texts. I've already tried a `TableView` similar to the one suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359718/aligning-two-linearlayout-side-by-side-inside-a-cardview), but it didn't help. I also tried to play with the margins of both elements but event when the picker was so "padded" that it was not visible, the text still remained at its position dispite being set to `center_vertical`.
I assume some hidden element belonging to the `TimePicker` is to be blame here, but I can't figure out what and how. What is the thing I'm not getting here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the gravity field in the TextView from "center_vertical" to just "center"

Edit: adding code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has the exact same result. Even if I give the picker a left padding as high as 50-60 and the text seemingly (?) has lots of space, it won't occupy it.

Comment: I also forgot to point out I changed the layout_width and layout_height properties. Did you change those also? I think the important one is the text view's layout_height should match parent.